# "Learn Python the Hard Way" Small Difficulty with example 26

Tags: python

I have my code here"

```
def break_words(stuff):
    """This function will break up words for us."""
    words = stuff.split(' ')
    return words

def sort_words(words):
    """Sorts the words."""
    return sorted(words)

def print_first_word(words):
    """Prints the first word after popping it off."""
    word = words.pop(0)
    print word

def print_last_word(words):
    """Prints the last word after popping it off."""
    word = words.pop(-1)
    print word

def sort_sentence(sentence):
    """Takes in a full sentence and returns the sorted words."""
    words = break_words(sentence)
    return sort_words(words)

def print_first_and_last(sentence):
    """Prints the first and last words of the sentence."""
    words = break_words(sentence)
    print_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)

def print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence):
    """Sorts the words then prints the first and last one."""
    words = sort_sentence(sentence)
    print_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)
```

And here are commands I input to run the functions:

```
sentence = "All good things come to those who wait"

words = break_words(sentence)
print words

word = sort_words(words)
print word

word = print_first_word(words)
print word

word = print_last_word(words)
print word

words = sort_sentence(sentence)
print sort_words(words)

print print_first_and_last(sentence)

print print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence)
```

However, running this in PowerShell gives me this:

```
All good things come to those who wait.

['All', 'good', 'things', 'come', 'to', 'those', 'who', 'wait.']

['All', 'come', 'good', 'things', 'those', 'to', 'wait.', 'who']

All

None

wait.

None

['All', 'come', 'good', 'things', 'those', 'to', 'wait.', 'who']

All

wait.

None

All

who

None
```

How can I get rid of the None that appears? All I want is the text that is above it.

Answer (score 2):

Every function that has no `return value` will return `None` by default. So for example when you  `print print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence)` you will see the output followed by `None`

You can just call the functions without using `print` or return the output in the functions.

Answer (score 0):

You do

```
word = print_first_word(words)
print word
```

where `print_first_word` prints the first word and then *doesn't return*. This means `word` will get set to `None`. You just need to avoid printing it:

```
print_first_word(words)
```

Eg.

```
sentence = "All good things come to those who wait"

words = break_words(sentence)
print words

word = sort_words(words)
print word

print_first_word(words)

print_last_word(words)

words = sort_sentence(sentence)
print sort_words(words)

print_first_and_last(sentence)

print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence)
```

Alternatively, you could make a `first_word` function that `return`s the value, and then run

```
print first_word(words)
```

For `print_first_and_last`, you could return `(first, last)` and do:

```
first, last = first_and_last(sentence)
print first
print last
```